# Unitary Transformation of Eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

Suppose I have two operators, $A$ and $B$, with eigenstates $A \lvert a \rangle = a \lvert a \rangle$ and $B \lvert b \rangle = b \lvert b \rangle$, where $a$ and $b$ are all unique. Furthermore, suppose that $A$ and $B$ are related by a unitary transformation $$A = U B U^{-1}.$$ This is equivalent to saying that the eigenstates are related as $$\lvert a \rangle = U \lvert b \rangle.$$

Then it seems I can prove the following: since $$A \lvert a \rangle = a \lvert a \rangle,$$ I also have $$A U \lvert b \rangle = U B U^\dagger U \lvert b \rangle$$ by inserting the identity, so that $$A U \lvert b \rangle = U B \lvert b \rangle = b U \lvert b \rangle = b \lvert a \rangle.$$ Thus, $a = b$.

Doesn't this imply then that the eigenvalues for corresponding eigenstates of $A$ and $B$ are equal, and therefore-- by the assumption that they are unique-- that the unitary transformation doesn't actually *do* anything?

Comment: As nicely summarized by @ZeroTheHero, when you write $A=UBU^{\dagger}$ you are performing a unitary basis change on operator $B$. $A$ is then the new representation of $B$ in this new set of basis. Eigenvalues are invariant under basis transformation . Thus, eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are the same, but their eigenstates are not.

Comment: Here is a good article if you're not sure why eigenvalues are invariant under basis transformation. ([link](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~ma130/eigen.pdf)).

Comment: It might help to choose as an example $A=x$ and $B=p$, where $U$ is the Fourier transform and takes $x$ to $p$. Here $x$ and $p$ have identical eigenvalue spectra, but that doesn't mean that the Fourier transform doesn't "do" anything.

Answer (score 10):

I’m not sure what you mean by “*$a$ and $b$ are unique*” but clearly if $A=UBU^\dagger$ and $U$ is unitary, $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues but it doesn’t mean $U$ doesn’t do anything.

For instance, the Pauli matrices $\sigma_{x,y,z}$ all have the same eigenvalues, are related by a unitary transformation $U$, but are certainly different.  The transformation $U$ is a change of basis, so if $B$ is initially diagonal, say
$$
B=\sigma_z=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0 \\ 0&-1\end{array}\right)
$$
and $U=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos\theta/2&-\sin\theta/2\\ \sin\theta/2 &\cos\theta/2\end{array}\right)$ then 
$$
U\sigma_zU^{\dagger}=\cos\theta\sigma_z+\sin\theta \sigma_x
$$
still have eigenvalues $\pm 1$ but obviously $U$ has done *something*.
Of course the eigenstates are no longer $\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\ 0\end{array}\right)$ and  $\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\ 1\end{array}\right)$.

Answer (score 4):

I interpret your uniqueness claim as the requirement that

**every eigenspace of either $A$ and $B$ has dimension $1$.**

So, if $a$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $A|a\rangle =a|a\rangle$, for $|a\rangle \neq 0$, then every other 
eigenvector with the same eigenvalue $a$ is of the form $c|a\rangle$ for every $c\in \mathbb C$, $c\neq 0$. If we consider only *normalized* eigenvectors, $c$ is of the form $e^{i \theta}$ for every $\theta \in \mathbb R$.

Assuming that the spectra of the said operators are *pure-point spectra*, we have the *spectral decompositions* (the sum are understood in the strong operator topology, but here it is quite irrelevant and you can safely interpret all follows at algebraic level)
$$A = \sum_{a \in {\cal A}} a |a\rangle\langle a| \tag{1}$$
and
$$B = \sum_{b\in {\cal B}} b |b\rangle\langle b| \:.$$
where I used normalized eigenvalues and ${\cal A}=\sigma(A)$, ${\cal B}=\sigma(B)$ (up to accumulation points) are the spectra of the operators.

On the other hand
$$A = UBU^\dagger$$ implies
$$\sum_{a \in {\cal A}} a |a\rangle\langle a| = \sum_{b \in {\cal B}} b U|b\rangle\langle b|U^\dagger\:.$$
That is 
$$A= \sum_{b \in {\cal B}}  b|\psi_b\rangle \langle \psi_b|\tag{2}$$
where $$|\psi_b\rangle := U|b\rangle\:.$$

The crucial result is now that

*for a given self-adjoint operator (with point spectrum) the spectral decomposition is unique*.

Thus,  comparing (1) and (2) we conclude that

(i)  ${\cal A}= {\cal B}\:,$

so that we can re-arrange the decomposition of $A$ like this
$$A= \sum_{a \in {\cal A}}  a|\psi_a\rangle \langle \psi_a|\:,$$

(ii) $|a\rangle \langle a| = |\psi_a\rangle \langle \psi_a|$ so that, since every vector is normalized
$$|\psi_a\rangle = e^{i\theta_a}|a\rangle\quad \mbox{for some $\theta_a \in \mathbb R$}\:.$$
there is no way to determine the phases $e^{i\theta_a}$, since normalized eigenvectors are defined up to a phase, but we are free to fix all them $ e^{i\theta_a}=1$.

I stress that (i) and (ii) are the maximum you can obtain from the initial information at your disposal that eigenspaces are  one-dimensional and that the unitary equivalence $A=UBU^\dagger$ holds.

You see that $U$ has an action (it is false that "it doesn't actually do anything"). In fact, it *changes eigenvectors*, but it *leaves fixed the spectrum* of the operators.

Dropping the hypotheses of one-dimensional eigenspaces but keeping the request of pure point spectrum,  (i) remains valid in view of the uniqueness of spectral decomposition, which now reads
$$A = \sum_{a \in {\cal A}} a P_a$$
where $P_a = \sum_{k=1}^{\dim E_a} |a,k\rangle \langle a,k|$ is the orthogonal projector onto the eigenspace $E_a$ of $A$ with eigenvalue $a$ and the vectors $|a,k\rangle$, varying $k=1,\ldots, \dim E_a$, form an orthonormal basis of that eigenspace.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a [similarity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) for an invertible (not necessary unitary) operator$^1$ $U$ *does* generically change the eigenspaces but does *not* change the eigenvalue spectrum $\{a_1, a_2,\ldots, \}=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots\}$. Hence it would be inconsistent to claim that all the eigenvalues $\{a_1,a_2, \ldots, b_1,b_2,\ldots\}$ for both $A$ and $B$ are different, if that's what OP means by that *they are all unique.* Whether the individual spectra are degenerate or not is irrelevant.

--

$^{1}$We will ignore subtleties with [unbounded operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator), domains, [selfadjoint extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_of_symmetric_operators), etc., in this answer.